# How to determine the type of Validation Error on Asp.Net Identity using Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Asp.Net Identity 2.0, Web Api 2 and .Net Framework 4.5.

I've implemented a validation filter for Web Api which captures all the model validation errors.

Asp.net Identity provides text errors for each model validation error but it doesn't provide a way to know the type of validation error. For example I don't need the text error "The phone parameter is required" but I do need to know that the error is a "Required" validation error or any attribute I had put on top of the property.

Example:

```
Class MyModel
{

  [Required]
  [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
  public string Phone {get; set;};

}
```

How can I know if the `ModelState` contains a`RequiredError` or a `StringLenght` error without reading the text error?

Answer (score 0):

You can read it directly from the property:

```
using System.Reflection;
var modelStateProperties = typeof(MyModel).GetProperties().Where(p => ModelState.Keys.Any(k => k == p.Name));
foreach (var property in modelStateProperties)
{
    // Found properties with errors in them
    var attrs = properties.GetCustomAttributes();
    // attrs now has the list of attributes, i.e., Required, StringLength, etc.
}
```

ModelState doesn't have what you need, the Model does. So, you have to find properties in `MyModel` with errors and loop through each property attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I think it doesn't solve my problem. I don't need to know the attributes of a property, what I need to know is the attribute related to a ModelState validation error. I mean when you are iterating through the ModelState.Value.Errors you get a item with a key and a value. I need to know if the data passed to the api is valid but also know what kind of error is it... is it required or stringlength or another else. Do you know how to do that?